# What do 3 dots/periods/ellipsis in a relay/graphql query mean?

Tags: relayjs, graphql

The [relay docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-object-identification.html#content) contain this fragment:

```
query RebelsRefetchQuery {
  node(id: "RmFjdGlvbjox") {
    id
    ... on Faction {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

What does this `... on Faction` on syntax mean?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There are two uses of `...` related to fragments.

## Incorporating a fragment by reference

```
query Foo {
  user(id: 4) {
    ...userFields
  }
}

fragment userFields on User {
  name
}
```

Has the effect of composing the fields from the fragment into the embedding query:

```
query Foo {
  user(id: 4) {
    name
  }
}
```

Note that fragments may compose other fragments.

## Inline fragments

From the docs:

> If you are querying a field that returns an interface or a union type, you will need to use inline fragments to access data on the underlying concrete type.

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments

These can be used to compose fields in a type-dependent way. For example:

```
query Foo {
  profile(id: $id) {
    url
    ... on User {
      homeAddress
    }
    ... on Business {
      address
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, the server will determine whether to return the `homeAddress` or `address` field at runtime, based on whether the requested object is a `User` or a `Business`.

Comment: I'm having trouble iterating on queries that contain fragments.  what do I do? I have no idea.

Comment: I only new of inline fragments before. Fragment syntax saves so many lines!

Answer (score 9):

Ah. It's explained [here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Fragments):

> Fragments are consumed by using the spread operator (...). All fields
>   selected by the fragment will be added to the query field selection at
>   the same level as the fragment invocation. This happens through
>   multiple levels of fragment spreads.